# Control specific instances of a class through instance variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class Class():
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name


class1 = Class(1, "Adam")
class2 = Class(2, "Bob")
class3 = Class(3, "John")

player_id = 1

if player_id == class1.id:
    print class1.name

elif player_id == class2.id:
    print class2.name

elif player_id == class3.id:
    print class3.name
#etc
```

What I want to do is shorten this code. For every class that I make, I'd have to add another block to this and that gets crazy after awhile. I want to be able to look if the player_id is the same as any of the classes, and control(find its name) that instance of the class if their IDs match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when you want O(1) lookup, you need to create a mapping using a `dictionary`.

```
id_map = {c.id: c for c in [class1, class2, class3]}
print id_map[player_id].name
```

Comment: This seems like the right answer, but I'll transfer it to the actual code to see if it works. Thank you :)

Comment: Ah, I'm terrible at asking questions. I didn't mention that name in Class is actually a list, didn't realize that would change everything. Your answer is correct for the question  asked, but I don't think there is an answer to what I'm doing. Looked it up some more, and apparently it's impossible without losing the ability to change the list (which is very important)

Comment: @AdamBurros Are you trying to compare lists?  Or just determine if a value exists in the list?

Comment: The list is only 2 coordinates, like [0,0] for each area, so I guess compare player_id to the coordinates. (player_id is also a list like [0,0], again not good at asking questions)

Comment: I figured out a workaround. I made a list of all of the classes and a function that searches through them and returns the class that has the same coordinate as the player, and it works well. It may not be very efficient, but eh. Thank you for all your help